# MUI DataGrid(Pro): How to pin or move the 'onRowOrderChange' icon to the left besides the pinned columns?

Tags: material-ui, datagrid, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm using MUI DataGridPro component with rowReordering and pinnedColumns. I want to move the draggable icon (the icon appears when using rowReordering, I 've colored it yellow in the image) to the left besides the other pinned columns, which is in the image, 'Desk'.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwPOI.png)

I tried to find the column name of rowReordering to pin it with 'Desk', but I couldn't find any kind of information.

Is there a way to move this icon besides the pinned columns or any way to pin it like other columns?